# Executing a function onclick via ejs template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am making a web application using node.js. I'm handling the server side via Express and using ejs templates to serve up the webpages. My issue is that I have a function  in my index.js file and it is referenced in my ejs file in the button's onclick event. Currently I'm only logging a statement in the console to make sure it works. Now every time I restart the server and open up my home route, I see the message logged into the console but when I click the actual button, nothing happens. The fuction executes on the server start/restart but not when the button is clicked. I've tried writing the function entirely inside the ejs page using the correct ejs syntax and tags. Every time the same issue occurs; the function executes when the homepage is refreshed and logs the message in the console but nothing happens when the button is clicked.

I'm guessing since I'm calling the function in the res.render route, it gets executed once the page is rendered. How do I go about making changes so that the function executes once the button is clicked?

Here's the function for the button (inside **index.js**):

```
function clicker() {
  console.log("Button Working!");
};
```

Here's the **index.js** code that handles the route for this function:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", {
    x: clicker()
  });
});
```

Button Tag inside my **home.ejs:**

```
<button class = 'btn btn-primary' onclick = "<%=x%>">Click Me!</button>
```

Console view:

[image: Message shows up when the homepage is loaded/refreshed.]

Comment: You are confusing client side and server side code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function itself instead of passing it:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", {
    x: clicker() // -> THIS GET EXECUTED
  });
});
```

Istead you should write

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", {
    x: clicker // -> THIS PASS AS OBJECT/FUNCTION
  });
});
```

Now it should get executed when you click on the button.

BUT: Im not sure if you define "clicker" on the server side, its gets passed to the client. The "clicker" function must be available on the client side, not server side. Move the defition on the client side and reference only the function name:

```js
{
  x: "clicker"
}
```

Comment: As suggested, I made the changes. Now the function doesn't run on page reload but still won't work when the button is clicked.

Comment: Can you post the compiled output ?

Comment: If you're asking for the console log then its pretty much the same as what I had originally posted in the question. With the exception of the "Button Working!" string.

Comment: I mean the render result that gets send to the client, is the site "live" on the internet or local ?